# Add custom widgets at runtime to screens

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I want to add Buttons (Basicly custom Buttons with Image) as a custom Widgets to "Screen1" but I always end up with "_event.pyx not found" Error.

I've tried with "super().**init**(**kwargs)" and without.

Python code:

```
sm = ScreenManager()

class DrinkWidget(Widget):
    pass

class HomeScreen(BoxLayout): 
    def switch(self, to):
        #Swithing funktion

#This is the Part, that causes the Problem I think:
class Screen1(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(DrinkWidget(
            lable_text_optn = 'test'
        ))

class Screen2(Screen):
    pass

class ZapfanlageApp(App):
    icon = 'GUI_Elemente/app_icon.png'
    title = 'Zapfanlage'
    def build(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ZapfanlageApp().run()
```

Kivy code (separate .kv File. The part "HomeScreen" works so far):

```
HomeScreen:
    sm: sm
    name: 'ScreenManager'

BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    rows: 2

    ActionBar:
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        size_hint_y: .065
        ActionView:
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Cocktails'
                on_press:
                    root.switch(1)
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Drinks'
                on_press:
                    root.switch(2)
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Einstellungen'
                on_press:
                    root.switch(3)

    ScreenManager:
        id: sm
        size_hint_y: .935

        Screen1:
            name: "screen1"
            id: screen1
        Screen2:
            name: "screen2"
            id: screen2

<Screen1@Screen>:
    name: "screen_1"
    id: screen1
    #Here should the Buttons in GridLayout appear

<Screen2@Screen>:
    name: "screen_2"
    id: screen2

#This is the Custom Button I want to be inserted above
<Drink_Widget@Button>:
    image_path_optn: image_path
    lable_text_optn: lable_text

Button:
    size_hint_x: None
    size_hint_y: None
    height: (root.height) -10
    width: 250
    on_press:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        width: root.width
        height: root.height
        pos_hint: root.pos
        pos: root.pos
        padding: 5
        Image:
            source: image_path
        Label:
            text: label_text
```

I want to show a various number of `DrinkWidget`s on `screen1` vertically and add them in runtime. But I always end up with nothing showing up or with `_event.pyx not found error`. Passing the code under `<Screen1@Screen>:` directly works.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you edit your post so there is proper indentation for all your code? Also when you try to write "Kivy code:" it looks like you meant to have that code inside your code block.

Comment: @Erik thank you for your hints. I've hopefully explained it better now and marked the most relevant points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it looks like you want to add a number of your `DrinkWidget`s to your screen when your app loads. First things first, in your `.py` file you have defined a class named `Drink_widget` but in `.kv` you call it `DrinkWidget`

Next, since you have your `DrinkWidget` defined as inheriting the `Button` class from kivy, you can easily change the text in the `DrinkWidget` using the `text:` field. Similarly, you can change the image that the button displays to be whatever you like using the `background_normal:` field. To change the image displayed when you click the button, use the `background_down:` field. Example:

```
<DrinkWidget@Button>:
    text: "some text"
    background_normal: "image1.png"
    background_down: "image2.png"
```

So you don't need your `lable_text_optn` or `image_path_optn` fields.

Also, you are trying to add a number of widgets to a `Screen` widget, when really you should be adding a number of widgets to a `Layout` widget (`FloatLayout`, `BoxLayout`, or `GridLayout`). Your `Screen` widget should only have the `Layout` widget as its direct child.

Another issue I see is you have two *root* widgets inside your `.kv` file -- `HomeScreen` and `BoxLayout` unless your indentation is correct in the question.

Here is a minimal example of what I believe you are trying to get working:

`main.py`

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class DrinkWidget(Button):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    def on_start(self):
        # This command is automatically called when your app loads up
        the_screen_grid = self.root.ids.some_descriptive_id
        # self.root refers to the root widget, which is the GridLayout
        # self.root.ids gets me a DictProperty of all children widgets that have an id associated with them
        # self.root.ids.some_descriptive_id gets me the GridLayout widget I defined with the id: some_descriptive_id
        for i in range(3):
            the_screen_grid.add_widget(DrinkWidget(text="drink " + str(i)))


MainApp().run()
```

`main.kv`

```
GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    Screen:
        # Widgets that aren't Layouts normally only have 1 child widget
        # To "add multiple widgets" to a screen, give the screen a Layout, then add widgets to the layout
        GridLayout:
            id: some_descriptive_id
            rows: 1
```

Your code is a bit too long to give you an exact solution for your case, but I hope this example gives you the knowledge to fix it up for yourself!

Comment: After a bit of testing I got it working! Thank you very much! Your answer was very good and understandable!

Comment: Fantastic, that's what I like to hear!